# How to force rollout in logback when there is no traffic in application

Tags: java, logback

so I have some default appender:

```
<appender name="appfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS_HOME}.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.CronTriggeringPolicy">
    
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>
```

this works when there is traffic in my application. But when application is not logging something like one day, last file is still not rollout. I see that `apache.logging.log4j` got something like `CronTriggeringPolicy` . Is there something similar to force rollout even there is no traffic in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

For various technical reasons, rollovers are not clock-driven but depend on the arrival of logging events. For example, on 29th of August 2020, assuming the fileNamePattern is set to yyyy-MM-dd (daily rollover), the arrival of the first event after midnight will trigger a rollover. If there are no logging events during, say 23 minutes and 47 seconds after midnight, then rollover will actually occur at 00:23'47 AM on August 30th and not at 0:00 AM. Thus, depending on the arrival rate of events, rollovers might be triggered with some latency. However, regardless of the delay, the rollover algorithm is known to be correct, in the sense that all logging events generated during a certain period will be output in the correct file delimiting that period. Refer: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

In your question, fileNamePattern is not correct and it should be as: ***<fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>***
and remove CronTriggeringPolicy.